# How much autonomy does one have in changing word-order in German in relation to parenthetical modifiers?

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause

I have just come across this sentence which does sound a bit awkward and heavy to my mind.

> Die Schüler sind nicht verpflichtet, eine Schuluniform zu tragen. Sie können sich kleiden, wie sie möchten.

Can we in this example postpone the main verb *kleiden* till after saying *wie sie möchten?*

Comment: There is nothing awkward or heavy at all about these sentences. They are as normal as they can come.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly do you think is awkward or heavy? Please edit your question and add a paragraph where you tell us what you think would be less awkward and heavy. How would you have written this sentence?

Comment: In English, nobody would say *"They can as they like dress"*. The same in German: the sentence *"Sie können sich wie sie möchten ankleiden"* sounds awkward; the sentence as written above does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can, but the cited form sounds *less* awkward than your proposed shift. The German *Verbklammer* is deeply ingrained in our sense for language, but even we Germans tend to avoid interrupting it with an entire relative clause.

Comment: The *awkwardness* comes IMHO from the two infinitives following each other directly and would be generally considered bad style.